# Converting and validating url from untrusted source

Tags: java, url, html-parsing

I'm parsing web page and collecting hrefs. Because web page is untrusted source it can hold links with invalid syntax or non-ascii symbols. So, as I understand, I need

1) convert spaces and non-ascii symbols and other symbols

2) validate string that was produced by step 1 (validness criteria: this url can be typed in browser and it will be able to retrieve page represented by url, such url can be constructed by  URL/URI constructors and than appropriate page retrieved - I can type some urls in firefox but can't construct instances in java)

3) construct java.net.URL/URI from (1) if it is valid

I had found two validation libraries: [1](http://matalon.org/search-algorithms/doc/org/matalon/pagerankhits/util/UrlUtil.html) and [2](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html) (which one do you prefer?) but no adequate library for first clause (tools like java.net.URLDecoder/URLEncoder) aren't intended for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just try to make an URL/URI from it in a try/catch statement? I think that class' constructor handles the validation automatically

Comment: What would you need to convert?!

Comment: >"convert spaces and non-ascii symbols and other symbols". You can type url in browser address panel and it will be automaticaly converted to valid url, but if you will try to construct URI/URL via appropriate constructors, you can get IllegalSyntaxException.

Comment: The constructor new URL(String) can only throw a MalformedURLException; this is when no http:// or anything is specified. It will take care of the rest!?